# In scala, how to find all occurrence of \\$[0-9]+ in a string and replace them

Tags: regex, scala

The following simple code failed (I expect the result to be `"abc$1%s"`):

```
  "\\$[0-9]+".r
    .replaceAllIn(
      "abc$1", {
        mtch =>
          mtch.toString() + "%s"
      })
```

With

```
No group 1
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

I have correctly escaped dollar sign and avoid all lookforward/lookback control characters, why it still fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group error means you don't have a parenthesis delimited group defined.

Something like `"(\\$[0-9]+)"` would define your whole regex as a group.